# Wifi breaks all the time - Ubuntu 18.04 - [14e4:4331]

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, network-manager, broadcom

The problem is that my wifi connection breaks all the time irregularly, in the span of after 5 minutes and sometimes after 30 minutes. When this happens I have to `sudo service network-manager restart`.
This is my wireless info:

```
 
########## wireless info START ##########

Report from: 04 Mar 2019 15:47 CET +0100

Booted last: 04 Mar 2019 00:00 CET +0100

Script from: 22 Oct 2018 03:34 UTC +0000

##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic

##### kernel ############################

Linux 4.18.0-15-generic #16~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Feb 7 14:06:04 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, quiet, splash, vt.handoff=1

##### desktop ###########################

i3

##### lspci #############################

02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries NetXtreme BCM57786 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe [14e4:16a3] (rev 21)
    Subsystem: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries NetXtreme BCM57786 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe [14e4:16a3]

02:00.1 SD Host controller [0805]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM57765/57785 SDXC/MMC Card Reader [14e4:16bc] (rev 21)

03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM4331 802.11a/b/g/n [14e4:4331] (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Apple Inc. AirPort Extreme [106b:010f]
    Kernel driver in use: wl

##### lsusb #############################

Bus 002 Device 005: ID 05ac:025a Apple, Inc. 
Bus 002 Device 008: ID 05ac:828c Apple, Inc. 
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 0a5c:4500 Broadcom Corp. BCM2046B1 USB 2.0 Hub (part of BCM2046 Bluetooth)
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0424:2512 Standard Microsystems Corp. USB 2.0 Hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 05ac:8510 Apple, Inc. FaceTime HD Camera (Built-in)
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 058f:6387 Alcor Micro Corp. Flash Drive
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

##### rfkill ############################

0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: brcmwl-0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

##### secure boot #######################

This system doesn't support Secure Boot

##### lsmod #############################

wl                   6447104  0
cfg80211              667648  1 wl

##### interfaces ########################

[/etc/network/interfaces]
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

##### ifconfig ##########################

1: lo:  mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback  brd 
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: wlp3s0:  mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether  brd 
    inet 192.168.178.37/24 brd 192.168.178.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute wlp3s0
       valid_lft 863787sec preferred_lft 863787sec
    inet6 fe80::efa4:b431:4d6b:6c87/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

##### iwconfig ##########################

lo        no wireless extensions.

wlp3s0    IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"Maria"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.417 GHz  Access Point:    
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on


##### route #############################

default via 192.168.178.1 dev wlp3s0 proto dhcp metric 600 
169.254.0.0/16 dev wlp3s0 scope link metric 1000 
192.168.178.0/24 dev wlp3s0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.178.37 metric 600 

##### resolv.conf #######################

[777 root '/etc/resolv.conf' -> '../run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf']

nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0
search fritz.box

##### network managers ##################

Installed:

    NetworkManager

Running:

root       856     1  0 15:43 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon

##### NetworkManager info ###############

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         wlp3s0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           wifi
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceWifi
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Broadcom Limited
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        BCM4331 802.11a/b/g/n
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         wl
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 6.30.223.271 (r587334)
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               --
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
GENERAL.REASON:                         0 (No reason given)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.1/0000:03:00.0/net/wlp3s0
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       wlp3s0
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     Maria
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       2056ccd4-49d7-496c-ae43-2d0b8d339502
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/1
GENERAL.METERED:                        no (guessed)
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            no
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     130 Mb/s
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
CAPABILITIES.SRIOV:                     no
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WEP:                    yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WPA:                    yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WPA2:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.TKIP:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.CCMP:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.AP:                     no
WIFI-PROPERTIES.ADHOC:                  yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.2GHZ:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.5GHZ:                   yes
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         192.168.178.37/24
IP4.GATEWAY:                            192.168.178.1
IP4.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 0.0.0.0/0, nh = 192.168.178.1, mt = 600
IP4.ROUTE[2]:                           dst = 192.168.178.0/24, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 600
IP4.ROUTE[3]:                           dst = 169.254.0.0/16, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 1000
IP4.DNS[1]:                             192.168.178.1
IP4.DOMAIN[1]:                          fritz.box
DHCP4.OPTION[1]:                        requested_subnet_mask = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[2]:                        requested_rfc3442_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[3]:                        subnet_mask = 255.255.255.0
DHCP4.OPTION[4]:                        domain_name_servers = 192.168.178.1
DHCP4.OPTION[5]:                        ip_address = 192.168.178.37
DHCP4.OPTION[6]:                        requested_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[7]:                        dhcp_server_identifier = 192.168.178.1
DHCP4.OPTION[8]:                        requested_time_offset = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[9]:                        broadcast_address = 192.168.178.255
DHCP4.OPTION[10]:                       requested_interface_mtu = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[11]:                       dhcp_rebinding_time = 756000
DHCP4.OPTION[12]:                       requested_domain_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[13]:                       dhcp_message_type = 5
DHCP4.OPTION[14]:                       requested_broadcast_address = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[15]:                       routers = 192.168.178.1
DHCP4.OPTION[16]:                       dhcp_renewal_time = 432000
DHCP4.OPTION[17]:                       requested_domain_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[18]:                       domain_name = fritz.box
DHCP4.OPTION[19]:                       requested_routers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[20]:                       expiry = 1552574634
DHCP4.OPTION[21]:                       requested_wpad = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[22]:                       requested_netbios_scope = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[23]:                       requested_ms_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[24]:                       requested_netbios_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[25]:                       network_number = 192.168.178.0
DHCP4.OPTION[26]:                       requested_domain_search = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[27]:                       next_server = 192.168.178.1
DHCP4.OPTION[28]:                       requested_ntp_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[29]:                       ntp_servers = 192.168.178.1
DHCP4.OPTION[30]:                       requested_host_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[31]:                       dhcp_lease_time = 864000
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         fe80::efa4:b431:4d6b:6c87/64
IP6.GATEWAY:                            --
IP6.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = ff00::/8, nh = ::, mt = 256, table=255
IP6.ROUTE[2]:                           dst = fe80::/64, nh = ::, mt = 256
IP6.ROUTE[3]:                           dst = fe80::/64, nh = ::, mt = 600
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/{1}
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[1]:   2056ccd4-49d7-496c-ae43-2d0b8d339502 | Maria

SSID            BSSID              MODE   CHAN  FREQ      RATE        SIGNAL  BARS  SECURITY   ACTIVE  IN-USE 
Maria             Infra  2     2417 MHz  270 Mbit/s  70      ▂▄▆_  WPA1 WPA2  no             
Maria             Infra  2     2417 MHz  270 Mbit/s  68      ▂▄▆_  WPA2       yes     *      
Maria             Infra  6     2437 MHz  195 Mbit/s  49      ▂▄__  WPA2       no             
Nadine            Infra  1     2412 MHz  130 Mbit/s  32      ▂▄__  WPA2       no             
Maria             Infra  44    5220 MHz  405 Mbit/s  32      ▂▄__  WPA2       no             
FRITZ!Box 7312    Infra  11    2462 MHz  270 Mbit/s  20      ▂___  WPA1 WPA2  no             

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager config #############

[[/etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf]]
[connection]
wifi.powersave = 3

[[/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf]]
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile
[ifupdown]
managed=false
[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-dns-resolved.conf]]
[main]
dns=systemd-resolved

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-globally-managed-devices.conf]]
[keyfile]
unmanaged-devices=*,except:type:wifi,except:type:wwan

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/20-connectivity-ubuntu.conf]]
[connectivity]
uri=http://connectivity-check.ubuntu.com/

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/no-mac-addr-change.conf]]
[device-mac-addr-change-wifi]
match-device=driver:rtl8723bs,driver:rtl8189es,driver:r8188eu,driver:8188eu,driver:eagle_sdio,driver:wl
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no
wifi.cloned-mac-address=preserve
ethernet.cloned-mac-address=preserve

##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Maria]] (600 root)
[connection] id=Maria | type=wifi | permissions=
[wifi] mac-address= | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=Maria
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

##### Netplan config ####################

[/etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml]
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager

##### iw reg get ########################

Region: Europe/Berlin (based on set time zone)

global
country GB: DFS-ETSI
    (2402 - 2482 @ 40), (N/A, 20), (N/A)
    (5170 - 5250 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), AUTO-BW
    (5250 - 5330 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS, AUTO-BW
    (5490 - 5710 @ 160), (N/A, 27), (0 ms), DFS
    (57000 - 66000 @ 2160), (N/A, 40), (N/A)

##### iwlist channels ###################

lo        no frequency information.

wlp3s0    32 channels in total; available frequencies :
          Channel 01 : 2.412 GHz
          Channel 02 : 2.417 GHz
          Channel 03 : 2.422 GHz
          Channel 04 : 2.427 GHz
          Channel 05 : 2.432 GHz
          Channel 06 : 2.437 GHz
          Channel 07 : 2.442 GHz
          Channel 08 : 2.447 GHz
          Channel 09 : 2.452 GHz
          Channel 10 : 2.457 GHz
          Channel 11 : 2.462 GHz
          Channel 12 : 2.467 GHz
          Channel 13 : 2.472 GHz
          Channel 36 : 5.18 GHz
          Channel 38 : 5.19 GHz
          Channel 40 : 5.2 GHz
          Channel 42 : 5.21 GHz
          Channel 44 : 5.22 GHz
          Channel 46 : 5.23 GHz
          Channel 48 : 5.24 GHz
          Channel 52 : 5.26 GHz
          Channel 56 : 5.28 GHz
          Channel 60 : 5.3 GHz
          Channel 64 : 5.32 GHz
          Channel 100 : 5.5 GHz
          Channel 104 : 5.52 GHz
          Channel 108 : 5.54 GHz
          Channel 112 : 5.56 GHz
          Channel 116 : 5.58 GHz
          Channel 120 : 5.6 GHz
          Channel 124 : 5.62 GHz
          Channel 128 : 5.64 GHz
          Current Frequency=2.417 GHz (Channel 2)

##### iwlist scan #######################

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

Channel occupancy:

      2   APs on   Frequency:2.417 GHz (Channel 2)
      1   APs on   Frequency:2.437 GHz (Channel 6)
      1   APs on   Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)
      1   APs on   Frequency:5.22 GHz (Channel 44)

wlp3s0    Scan completed :
          Cell 01 - Address: 
                    Channel:2
                    Frequency:2.417 GHz (Channel 2)
                    Quality=60/70  Signal level=-50 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"Maria"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s
                              9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=0000000000000000
                    Extra: Last beacon: 8ms ago
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
          Cell 02 - Address: 
                    Channel:2
                    Frequency:2.417 GHz (Channel 2)
                    Quality=53/70  Signal level=-57 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"Maria"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s
                              18 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 24 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=0000000000000000
                    Extra: Last beacon: 8ms ago
                    IE: WPA Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : TKIP CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : TKIP CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
          Cell 03 - Address: 
                    Channel:6
                    Frequency:2.437 GHz (Channel 6)
                    Quality=40/70  Signal level=-70 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"Maria"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s
                              9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=0000000000000000
                    Extra: Last beacon: 8ms ago
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
          Cell 04 - Address: 
                    Channel:11
                    Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)
                    Quality=23/70  Signal level=-87 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"FRITZ!Box 7312"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s
                              9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=0000000000000000
                    Extra: Last beacon: 8ms ago
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: WPA Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
          Cell 05 - Address: 
                    Channel:44
                    Frequency:5.22 GHz (Channel 44)
                    Quality=32/70  Signal level=-78 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"Maria"
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s; 24 Mb/s
                              36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=0000000000000000
                    Extra: Last beacon: 8ms ago
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK

##### module infos ######################

[wl]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.18.0-15-generic/updates/dkms/wl.ko
license:        MIXED/Proprietary
srcversion:     00D38A27B7E3C7B97C238FC
depends:        cfg80211
retpoline:      Y
name:           wl
vermagic:       4.18.0-15-generic SMP mod_unload 
signat:         PKCS#7
signer:         
sig_key:        
sig_hashalgo:   md4
parm:           passivemode:int
parm:           wl_txq_thresh:int
parm:           oneonly:int
parm:           piomode:int
parm:           instance_base:int
parm:           nompc:int
parm:           intf_name:string

[cfg80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.18.0-15-generic/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
description:    wireless configuration support
license:        GPL
author:         Johannes Berg
srcversion:     BFB309EF7C6C321F605D36E
depends:        
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           cfg80211
vermagic:       4.18.0-15-generic SMP mod_unload 
signat:         PKCS#7
signer:         
sig_key:        
sig_hashalgo:   md4
parm:           bss_entries_limit:limit to number of scan BSS entries (per wiphy, default 1000) (int)
parm:           ieee80211_regdom:IEEE 802.11 regulatory domain code (charp)
parm:           cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz:Disable 40MHz support in the 2.4GHz band (bool)

##### module parameters #################

[cfg80211]
bss_entries_limit: 1000
cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz: N
ieee80211_regdom: 00

##### /etc/modules ######################

##### modprobe options ##################

[/etc/modprobe.d/amd64-microcode-blacklist.conf]
blacklist microcode

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-bcm43.conf]
blacklist b43
blacklist b43legacy
blacklist ssb
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist brcm80211
blacklist brcmfmac
blacklist brcmsmac
blacklist bcma

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist i2c_i801
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/intel-microcode-blacklist.conf]
blacklist microcode

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211

##### rc.local ##########################

grep: /etc/rc.local: No such file or directory

##### pm-utils ##########################

##### udev rules ########################

##### dmesg #############################

[    5.622845] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp3s0: link is not ready (repeated 2 times)
[    9.275412] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp3s0: link becomes ready
[   17.524207] CPU: 0 PID: 442 Comm: wl_event_handle Tainted: P           OE     4.18.0-15-generic #16~18.04.1-Ubuntu
[   17.524288]  wl_bss_roaming_done.isra.24+0xd6/0x130 [wl]
[   17.524315]  ? wl_bss_roaming_done.isra.24+0xd6/0x130 [wl]
[   17.524338]  wl_notify_roaming_status+0x35/0x80 [wl]
[   17.524363]  wl_event_handler+0x7a/0x1f0 [wl]
[   17.524387]  ? wl_notify_scan_status+0x330/0x330 [wl]
[   26.644199] CPU: 1 PID: 442 Comm: wl_event_handle Tainted: P        W  OE     4.18.0-15-generic #16~18.04.1-Ubuntu
[   26.644299]  wl_bss_roaming_done.isra.24+0xd6/0x130 [wl]
[   26.644330]  ? wl_bss_roaming_done.isra.24+0xd6/0x130 [wl]
[   26.644359]  wl_notify_roaming_status+0x35/0x80 [wl]
[   26.644390]  wl_event_handler+0x7a/0x1f0 [wl]
[   26.644422]  ? wl_notify_scan_status+0x330/0x330 [wl]
[   61.559411] CPU: 1 PID: 442 Comm: wl_event_handle Tainted: P        W  OE     4.18.0-15-generic #16~18.04.1-Ubuntu
[   61.559563]  wl_bss_roaming_done.isra.24+0xd6/0x130 [wl]
[   61.559610]  ? wl_bss_roaming_done.isra.24+0xd6/0x130 [wl]
[   61.559656]  wl_notify_roaming_status+0x35/0x80 [wl]
[   61.559704]  wl_event_handler+0x7a/0x1f0 [wl]
[   61.559748]  ? wl_notify_scan_status+0x330/0x330 [wl]
[  222.821431] ERROR @wl_dev_intvar_get : 

########## wireless info END ############
```

I use an MacBook Pro late 2012 with Ubuntu 18.04 and i3 wm. Thanks for any help.
Additionally the wifi breaks every time after suspend and I do not have a fix for this neither.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can switch to another driver. Run

```
sudo apt install firmware-b43-installer
sudo apt purge bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo modprobe b43
```

and test your Wi-Fi.

Comment: Im trying right now. The third command gives me `modprobe: FATAL: Module wl not found`. What should I do?

Comment: Just go ahead. it's OK It has been removed by the previous command.

Comment: Somehow even the first two lines seemed to have worked. Thanks once again!